# Navigating to source from "Analyze Stacktrace" on Windows while running in Linux

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am developing on a Python project using IntelliJ on Windows, but running the code on a linux box. Stacktraces are therefore in linux style format e.g. /a/b/c.py.

How can the stacktrace be navigable to the source files in intellij's Analyze Stacktrace window?

I would like to be able to click the linux path in the stacktrace and have intellij navigate to the appropriate source file, the same way a stacktrace generated on Windows would have been.

When I use a runner (python or unittests) I can define a path mapping from my Windows path to the Linux path, so the pathnames are clickable and navigable to the relevant file & line. When I use the Analyze Stacktrace window, for example to analyze a stacktrace sent by email, the paths are not navigable and I could not find a way to define a path mapping for the Analyze Stacktrace window.